# Using Retry-After header in response for non 503/3xx

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

We have an interesting case for a REST backend that we are implementing at work where the process of initializing one of our entities is asynchronous (unfortunately there is nothing we can do about this). Since the initialization method is asynchronous, this means that REST endpoints which alter this method can fail if the entity has not yet been initialized.

To avoid polling when the entity is ready on the backend, I am attempting whether to use the status code `409` + the `Retry-After` header. The idea is that if a client attempts to change the entity when its being asynchronously initialized, we would return `409` + the `Retry-After` with a value of lets say 5 seconds asking the client to retry the same request in 5 seconds (repeating the process until the entity is initialized).

My question is whether this is a valid use for of the `Retry-After` header, the RFC spec isn't entirely clear whether the `Retry-After` header can only be sent in `503`/`3xx`, see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.3 for more details.

We of course could just use the `503` status code, however its a bit deceptive since its not that our service is unavailable (rather its that an entity is still being initialized, hence why we want to use the `409` status code)

Comment: Just another point of view: the service is unavailable (for now) due to entity initialization and `503` is returned, it looks pretty fine :)

Comment: @mdedetrich I am currently in the _exact_ same scenario as what you describe... any chance you ended up finalizing your approach by now? :)  What response did you end up deciding to go with?

Comment: Just noticed the comment now, I honestly can't remember. This a problem I had long ago in a company that I am no longer working for.